# Getting column mean by summing values of another column

Tags: python

I have a Dataframe with three columns `Customer`, `Purchase amount` and `Purchase date`.

I need to get sum of `Purchase amount` of customer purchases for each day, then get mean of purchases for each customer for one month.

I've tried to use `df.pivot_table()` but it takes mean of purchases for one day and then mean of purchases for one month.

Hope you can help me.

My Dataframe:

```
lst = [['Customer1', 100, '10.01.2020'], ['Customer1', 210, '10.01.2020'], ['Customer1', 122, '10.01.2020'],
       ['Customer1', 259, '10.13.2020'], ['Customer1', 160, '10.13.2020'], ['Customer1', 225, '10.13.2020'],
       ['Customer1', 310, '10.15.2020'], ['Customer1', 310, '10.15.2020'], ['Customer1', 310, '10.15.2020'],
       ['Customer2', 50, '10.21.2020'], ['Customer2', 70, '10.21.2020'], ['Customer2', 100, '10.21.2020'],
       ['Customer2', 120, '10.25.2020'], ['Customer2', 140, '10.25.2020'], ['Customer2', 155, '10.25.2020'],
       ['Customer2', 40, '10.27.2020'], ['Customer2', 30, '10.27.2020'], ['Customer2', 80, '10.27.2020']]

df = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns = ['Customer', 'Amount', 'Purchase date'])



   Customer  Amount Purchase date
0   Customer1     100    10.01.2020
1   Customer1     210    10.01.2020
2   Customer1     122    10.01.2020
3   Customer1     259    10.13.2020
4   Customer1     160    10.13.2020
5   Customer1     225    10.13.2020
6   Customer1     310    10.15.2020
7   Customer1     310    10.15.2020
8   Customer1     310    10.15.2020
9   Customer2      50    10.21.2020
10  Customer2      70    10.21.2020
11  Customer2     100    10.21.2020
12  Customer2     120    10.25.2020
13  Customer2     140    10.25.2020
14  Customer2     155    10.25.2020
15  Customer2      40    10.27.2020
16  Customer2      30    10.27.2020
17  Customer2      80    10.27.2020
```

I've tried to use:

```
df.pivot_table(index = 'Customer', columns = 'Purchase date', values = 'Amount', aggfunc = 'mean', margins = True)
```

Result:

```
Purchase date   10.01.2020  10.13.2020  10.15.2020  10.21.2020  10.25.2020  10.27.2020  Mean
Customer                            
Customer1          144          214        310          NaN         NaN         NaN     222
Customer2           NaN         NaN        NaN          73          138         50       87
```

Here is what I need to get:

```
  Purchase date 10.01.2020  10.13.2020  10.15.2020  10.21.2020  10.25.2020  10.27.2020  Mean                        
  Customer1        432          644        930         NaN          NaN        NaN      668
  Customer2        NaN          NaN        NaN         220           415      150.0     261
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
df['Purchase date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Purchase date'])
# create a month column
df['month'] = df['Purchase date'].apply(lambda x: x.month)
```

For getting the sum for each day use `groupby`

```py
df.groupby(by=['Purchase date', 'Customer']).sum()
```

output

```
Purchase date   Customer Amount month       
2020-10-01  Customer1   432     30
2020-10-13  Customer1   644     30
2020-10-15  Customer1   930     30
2020-10-21  Customer2   220     30
2020-10-25  Customer2   415     30
2020-10-27  Customer2   150     30
```

For monthly average again use `groupby`

```py
df.groupby(by=['month','Customer'] ).mean()
```

output

```
        
month   Customer    Amount
10  Customer1   222.888889
Customer2   87.222222
```

---

Looking at what you are trying to achieve can be done using `pivot table` as

```py
df = df.pivot_table(index = 'Customer', columns = 'Purchase date', values = 'Amount', aggfunc = 'sum', margins = True, margins_name='mean')
df['mean'] = df.apply(lambda x: round(x['mean']/(x.count()-1)), axis=1)
```

output

```
Purchase date   10.01.2020  10.13.2020  10.15.2020  10.21.2020  10.25.2020  10.27.2020  mean
Customer                            
Customer1   432.0   644.0   930.0   NaN    NaN      NaN     669.0
Customer2   NaN     NaN     NaN     220.0  415.0    150.0   262.0
mean       432.0    644.0   930.0   220.0   415.0   150.0   930.0
```

Comment: But your solution with df.pivot_table() doesn't work out for a large Dataframe with thousands of records. Thanks for you effort.

Comment: I doesn't throw error. For example: If Dataframe has 1000 rows(customers) and each customer made 3 purchases, Mean/len(df) divides the number by 1000 (when it should divide it by 3). So the expected mean value is becoming very low.

Comment: The mena that you asked in the question wasn't clear. So by guess I decided the total with the number of rows and that match your  asked value. Original mean was 222 and 87. So how are you calculating your mean? Alt east clarify the logic.

Comment: Mean = total of every month / total number of customers. If it is the logic then the question u asked should have mean 1003 not 668

Comment: Your answer solves this specific case. It just doesn't work out for my dataset, as I have 1000 customers which made 3-5 purchases for 1 month. Mean logic is - total amount of customer purchases/total number of purchases of that customer. So for example: If I will have 4 customers and each of them made 3 purchases for this month, your solution will divide total amount of purchase of 1 customer by '5'(because Dataframe will have 5 rows), not by '3'(total number of purchases of 1 customer) as it should actually do.

Comment: @OlzhasKaskelov  Okay, I have changed the code according to that.